# Can a git folder be used from a portable hard drive

Tags: git

I was happy coding on my laptop, when one day my laptop broke. Luckily, I had saved my work, but not made a commit to bitbucket.

I removed the old hard-drive and bought an enclosure for it. Plugged it into another laptop with git installed, navigated to my local repo via git bash and tried pulling off the updates, that my friend had made. This gave me an authentication error. I tried generating a new ssh key, but this was the same as the old one.

Is it possible, what I tried? Is a cloned repo somehow tied to a certain hardware? How can I get to work?

It would be nice to work this way, as I won't be tied to a machine and I can store my old hard-drive away at night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by following the instructions on this page:

Set up SSH for Git and Mercurial on Mac OSX/Linux https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678

The instructions are more comprehensive than other links

Answer (score 2):

> Is what i tried even possible, is a cloned repo somehow tied to a certain hardware

No, a repo isn't tied to an hardware. At all.

If you can clone the BitBucket repo, all you need to do is:

```
cd /your/local/clone
git status --work-tree=/path/to/your/backup/repo
git add -A --work-tree=/path/to/your/backup/repo
```

That will detect any changes introduced in the old repo.

Once added, you can commit as normal

```
git commit -m "restore changes."
```

Comment: i cloned it when my laptop was fine. When it broke I placed the HD into a case and accessed the git folder from another machine.I thought I could carry on as usual just by doing a cd to that folder.

Comment: @ImranNazir what does `git remote -v` returns when you are in that folder?

Comment: Hi i have done a clone now to get me up and running; but to anseer your question it returns two lines something like this: origin "path to remote repo" (fetch) and origin "path to remote repo" (push)

Answer (score 1):

The git repository is defined by the `.git` folder at the root.

All references inside this .git folder are purely relative, there's nothing tying it to a specific place or hardware, you can move it or copy it without any problem.

The problem you have seems to be uniquely related to ssh authorization, which is managed totally out of git. Fix your ssh problem and ensure you can do basic ssh operations like `scp`, then you'll probably be able to use your repo on your new laptop.

Comment: Yes I thought the same. Then why am I suddenly getting access issues when I git pull --all

Comment: You use another laptop, you say. Can you use standard ssh commands like for example `scp` ?

Comment: Yes, when I type scp at the terminal I get the usage info. Please not that I am new to Git

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to setup a GIT repo on my local development machine, just using other folder.
So I did following:

1. created folder: /Git/repos/
2. cd /Git/repos && git init --bare develop
3. git remote add /Git/repos/develop
4. git push -u develop master

NOTE!!! that when adding git remote, the remote is WITHOUT .git extension. Just plain folder name.